# Count the number of elements in a list using java8 features

Tags: java, java-8

```
    List<String> strList1 = Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
    List<String> strList2 = Arrays.asList("ddd", "eee", "fff");
    List<List<String>> list = Arrays.asList(strList1,strList2);

    int noOfElements = (int) list.stream().flatMap(i->i.stream()).count();
    System.out.println(noOfElements);
```

I want to count the number of individual `Strings`(as done in above code snippet). I am able to do so after flattening the list, but I want to do the same **without** using `flatMap()`. There has to be someway to get the count. Thanks in advance.

Comment: list.size() does not work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can `map` the individual lists to their `size` and calculate the `sum`:

```
int noOfElements = list.stream().mapToInt(List::size).sum();
```

Or using `reduce` instead, as suggested [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370194/count-the-number-of-elements-in-a-list-using-java8-features/42370261#comment71890450_42370261) by @MarkusBenko:

```
int noOfElements = list.stream().reduce(0, (i, l) -> i + l.size(), (i, j) -> i + j)
```

Comment: Perfect! Is there anyway we can do the same using `reduce`?

Comment: `int noOfElements = list.stream().reduce(0, (i, l) -> i + l.size(), (i, j) -> i + j)`

Comment: @NisargPatil Sure, just use `.reduce(0, (x, y) -> x + y)` instead of `sum()`, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: just trying to understand the thing in depth. Thanks!